# HTML pattern regex at least one space between characters

Tags: regex, html

I need an HTML pattern regex at least one space between characters and allowing more than one space in the field.

Example:

```
`'XXXX XXXX'  or 'XXXX XXXX XXXX' or 'XX XXX XXXX XXX'`
```

I've tried the pattern`.+/s` but it does not work in HTML5.

Comment: Probably `pattern="\S+(?:\s+\S+)+"` or, to also allow leading/trailing spaces, `pattern="\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+)+\s*"`. If you just want to make sure there is at least one `\s` and `\S`, use ``pattern="(?=\S*\s)(?=\s*\S).+"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is regex you need I think:

```
/([^\s]+\s)+[^\s]+/g
```

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/471s3

It matches `XXXX XXXX` and `X X X` but not `XXX`

Comment: X can be any character

Comment: I updated the regex - you can use [^\s] to match any character different than whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute "pattern" in your input field.
Pattern must content **"\D{4}\s\D{4}|\D{4}\s\D{4}\s\D{4}|\D{2}\s\D{3}\s\D{4}\s\D{3}"**
With this pattern will be one right value of  'XXXX XXXX'  or 'XXXX XXXX XXXX' or 'XX XXX XXXX XXX'

Comment: The number of characters may vary, it does not exactly follow the posted example. And yes, it will be used in the input pattern of the input field.

Comment: may be like this (\D{1,}\s\D{1,}){1,} ?

Comment: I change to ((\w|\W){1,}\s(\w|\W){1,}){1,}?

Comment: it must accept all different character types of space.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

> ^[a-zA-Z.\'-]{1,}(?: [a-zA-Z.\'-]{1,})+$

https://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/57